# How can I use python to make direct letter-to-number substitution?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to turn an inputted user name (Rex Ryan) into a 6 character name (ryanre) and change that to a numbered ID (A=01, B=02, ..., Z=26).

I've made an attempt at converting a full name into a 6 character name with this:

```
def converter():
    first = raw_input('What is the first name of the user? ')
    last = raw_input('What is the last name of the user? ')
    first[0:2] = firstname
    last[0:4] = lastname
    user = lastname + firstname
    print user
```

I keep getting "firstname is not defined" when I run it. Any direction or reading would be helpful; I'd like to do this mostly on my own. If I wanted it written for me I could just download something.

Comment: If this is homework you should specify so in your question.

Comment: This appears to be two questions: "why is my six-character name maker crashing?" and "how do I convert a string into a numbered ID?". Please ask only one question per post; otherwise, answerers will become disoriented, much like a dog becomes confused when you throw two tennis balls simultaneously during a game of fetch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your statements backward:

```
firstname = first[0:2]
```

As far as converting the return value to a sequence of numbers, have a look at [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord).  It will perform the mapping that you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, fixed my one problem. As for the numbers, will that only change to ASCII value or UNICODE? If so, is there a way to use dictionary or maketrans to make direct substitutions? The closes I've gotten is maketrans, though it won't allow me to use 01 as it's direct, character-for-character substitution.

Comment: @elock37 -- I'm not sure what you want to do with unicode.  Have a look at the link I posted.  It describes what `ord` does with unicode characters.  With a dict, it's pretty easy to substitute:  `d = {'A':'00',...}; s = ''; for c in yourname: s += d[c]` (which could be simplified more if you wanted).

Comment: I did look. ord does not appear to be able to do substitution. ord('a') returns 97, the ASCII table value of A. ord('a') - 96 returns 1. I need it to return 01.

Comment: @elock37 -- Sorry, you can do a simple shift.  `ord('a')-96`, `ord('b')-96`, etc.  Of course, this shift will put upper case characters as negative numbers ... Are you planning to be case sensitive?

Comment: @mgilson I plan on turning the user string to lowercase before converting it. However, subtracting will not return a two character digit which is what I need as all user IDs are 12 characters.

Comment: @elock37 -- `ord` returns a `int`.  If you google `python string formatting`, you should be able to turn it into a string pretty easily.  (`'%02d'%(ord(your_char)-96)` would work with old style formatting)

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like this:

```
def converter():
    first = raw_input('What is the first name of the user? ')
    last = raw_input('What is the last name of the user? ')
    firstname = first[0:2]
    lastname =  last[0:4]
    user = lastname + firstname
    print user
```

and for generating ID you can do something like this:

find the index of each letter in `ascii_lowercase` and increment all of them by 1 and concatenate them:

```
In [5]: from string import ascii_lowercase

In [6]: ascii_lowercase
Out[6]: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

In [7]: ''.join("{0:02}".format(ascii_lowercase.index(x)+1) for x in 'ryanre')
Out[7]: '182501141805'
```

Comment: Your `join` line needs to first `format` the generated strings so that A-I will have a leading 0 in the output as OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` so the name can be entered as a single string, `upper` to convert it to a single case, then `ord` combined with an offset value (hint: substract `ord('A')`) to get the numerical value you are looking for for each character.  You'll then want to look at string formatting to pad the single digit values with the leading 0 when building your output string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a dict to use as a look-up. First create a list op integers you want to use for the ID (here starting with 0).

```
t = 'ryanre'
num = list(range(25))
```

The BIF `chr()` is the inverse of `ord()` which was mentioned in other answers already. [Read up on the function here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr).

```
alpha = list(map(chr, range(97, 123)))
db = dict(zip(alpha,a)) # merge the lists into a dict
trasltd = [db[x] for x in t] 
res = ''.join(str(x) for x in trasltd) # merge the elements of the list
```